# Change font of one frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm writing a presentation using beamer, and I'd like to change the font of one frame only, or alternatively a part of one frame. I imagined this would be a common problem, but after quite a bit of searching I can't find anything that solves my problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me:

```
{
\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
Text to be in different font here
}
```

In this case, the different font is Latin Modern, which belongs to the family lmr.